# Can't see files uploaded by Paperclip on Rails 5.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm running Rails 5.1.4 and Paperclip 5.1

When i view my index file i get the following errors and images don't show up.  they do exist under /public/system/.../images/000/000/... location.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/recipes/images/000/000/008/medium/Capture777.PNG"):

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/recipes/images/000/000/011/medium/alaska_STandard_time.png"):
```

Comment: How're you trying to show the image in the view?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the image has been saved in the system folder, but you can't render it in the view is maybe due to a bad configuration in the options they're being defined in the model.

If you're using some style to show your image, like

- `model.attachment.url :style`

Try instead just accessing the image without the style being used, this way you can render it using an `image_tag` helper:

```
<% image_tag model.attachment.url %>
```

If it works, then the problem is in the paperclip config. in the respective model.

Comment: using image_tag worked.  Instructions mention to use :style so i thought it would be best way to have them all lined up properly.  How come it's in the instructions if this does not work or did i miss something in the instructions in order to use :style